# Algorithm to find next multiple

Tags: algorithm, math, pseudocode

Given two positive integers x and y, I need to find the next number greater than or equal to x that is a multiple of y.

For example:

> x=18, y=3 => 18

or

> x=18, y=5 => 20

or

> x=121, y=25 => 125

My first thought was to keep incrementing x until I find a match but that can get fairly inefficient for high y values.

Then I thought about `x - (x % y) + y` but that wont work if x is a multiple of y. Of course, I can always adjust for that using a ternary operator in the formula `x - ((x % y)==0?y:x % y) + y`.

Does anyone have any good, clever, simple suggestions or a complete solution that is better than what I have touched on? Am I missing something obvious in my logic?

I'll be using Java (this is a small piece of a greater algorithm), but pseudocode would be just as helpful if it is all straight math.

Comment: I actually like your solution..

Comment: I intuitively came up with your solution, there might be other smart tricks but I doubt you will find anything else more efficient.

Comment: You might consider asking this on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: n.m., you should post it as an answer!

Comment: Are we talking about positive integers?

Comment: n.m. your solution is promising (see RecommendedFormula2 from my answer). Care to add as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `x` and `y` are positive `int`s then this will work:

```
y * ((x-1)/y + 1);
```

Using the `x-1` allows you to not have to worry about the special case when `x` is a multiple of `y`. For example, if `y = 5`, then for `16 <= x <= 20`,

```
15 <= x-1 <= 19
(x-1)/y == 3
(x-1)/y+1 == 4
y*((x-1)/y+1) == 20
```

Comment: I've always regarded `y * ((x+y-1)/y)` as preferable to that.  The values are the same and the form slightly cleaner.

Comment: Your answer seems to test out fine when I plug it into the test class from my answer. Also, I like it better than my solution with the ternary. I think there is more than one correct answer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

Hm, what about?

```
tmp = ceil(x / y);
result = y * tmp;
```

Comment: This will not work if `x` and `y` are type `int`. i.e. `ceil(16/5) == ceil(3) == 3`, so you get `5*3 == 15`, but it should be `20`.

Comment: I added your suggestion as RecommendedFormula in the answer I have posted. I think JohnPS's comment may be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that x and y are greater than zero.

The mathematical formula is pretty simple:
Ceil(x / y) * y

where Ceil(x) is the smallest integral value that is greater than or equal to the specified real number

In Java you can use the function Math.ceil() for this purpose:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil(double)

Comment: I added your suggestion as RecommendedFormula in the answer I have posted (it is same as Pateman's answer). Do I just have the types wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. So far I have only had luck with my original solution but I'd still like to see something better. Here is a simple test class that I built to try and help facilitate ideas:

```
package com.scratch;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    private static class Values {
        long x;
        long y;
        long result;

        Values(long x, long y, long result) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.result = result;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Values> list = new ArrayList<Values>();
        Values v1 = new Values(18, 3, 18);
        list.add(v1);
        Values v2 = new Values(18, 5, 20);
        list.add(v2);
        Values v3 = new Values(121, 25, 125);
        list.add(v3);
        Values v4 = new Values(9999999, 10, 10000000);
        list.add(v4);

        Operation operation = new MyFormula();
        // Operation operation = new RecommendedFormula();
            // Operation operation = new RecommendedFormula2();
        for (Values v : list) {
            System.out.println(v.x + ", " + v.y + " => " + v.result + "?");
            long res = operation.perform(v.x, v.y);
            System.out.println(res == v.result ? "worked" : "nope... Expected "
                    + v.result + ", got " + res);
        }
    }

    private static interface Operation {
        long perform(long x, long y);
    }

    private static class MyFormula implements Operation {

        @Override
        public long perform(long x, long y) {
            return x - ((x % y) == 0 ? y : x % y) + y;
        }

    }

    private static class RecommendedFormula implements Operation {

        @Override
        public long perform(long x, long y) {
            return (long) (Math.ceil(x / y) * y);
        }

    }

private static class RecommendedFormula2 implements Operation{

        @Override
        public long perform(long x, long y) {
            return x + (y - x % y) % y;
        }

    }

}
```

MyFormula (which is in the question) seems to work just fine. RecommendedFormula does not, but that may only be because of the types I have used (which is what I will need to use in the finished product).

Comment: Added RecommendedFormula2 (from comments on question). Seems like winner?

Comment: To make RecommendedFormula work, you must cast at least oneof x and y to double before the division. Even then, it will produce wrong results for large x and/or y.